# Как в VBA Excel закрасить ячейки диапазона по условию?

Tags: excel, vba

Надо по некоторому условию закрасить строку в таблице Excel.
Пытаюсь пройти все ячейки в строке и закрасить их по отдельности.
Пробовал решения найденные в гугле:

```
Worksheets("List").Cells(1, 1).BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)

Worksheets("List").Cells(1, 1).Interrior.Color = vbRed
```

В обоих случаях получаю ошибку

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Судя по всему, я не правильно обращаюсь к свойствам ячейки.
Как закрашивать ячейки, и возможно получится закрасить всю строку или Range сразу, а не по ячейкам?

Comment: В первом коде - нет такого свойства. Во втором - тупо опечатка (используйте Intellisence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас лишняя буква   *r*   прицепилась :)

```
.Interior.Color = vbRed 
.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
.Interior.Color = 255
```

Работа с объектами листа медленная. Если ячеек много и заливать нужно не целым диапазоном, можно обработать в памяти и залить ячейки одной командой.

```
     Sub PaintCells()
            Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
            Dim c As Range
                Set r1 = Range("A1:C10") ' диапазон в переменную
                r1.Interior.Pattern = xlNone ' убираем заливку
'               r1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 ' или так 

                For Each c In r1 ' цикл по ячейкам диапазона
                    If c.Value = 25 Then ' если условие выполняется
                        If r2 Is Nothing Then '  диапазон еще пустой
                            Set r2 = c ' формируем диапазон
                        Else
                            Set r2 = Union(r2, c) ' пополняем диапазон
                        End If
                    End If
                Next c

                If Not r2 Is Nothing Then r2.Interior.Color = 255 ' заливаем
                Set r1 = Nothing: Set r2 = Nothing ' освобождаем память
            End Sub
```

Залить строки по условию  в ячейке:

```
For i = 1 To r1.Rows.Count ' цикл по строкам диапазона
    If r1(i, 1).Value = 25 Then ' если левая ячейка диапазона...
        If r2 Is Nothing Then '  диапазон еще пустой
            Set r2 = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3)) ' формируем диапазон
        Else
            Set r2 = Union(r2, Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 3))) ' пополняем диапазон
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте просто:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Лист1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 10)).Interior.Color = 100
```

чтобы, например, залить 1-ю строку с 1 по 10 ячейку.

<sub>P.S. У вас в слове `Interrior` ошибка, там 1 буква `r`, поэтому выскакивает ошибка о незнакомом методе.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> возможно получится закрасить всю строку или Range сразу, а не по ячейкам?

Ну так и красить надо строку, а не ячейки:

```
worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(1).Interior.Color=vbRed
```

Comment: Так я закрашу только не пустые ячейки или вообще все ячейки в строке до максимально возможного значения длины строки?

Comment: Ну не я же просил строку красить... а если надо красить Range - так и указывать в качестве объекта надо именно его. весь сразу, а не одну ячейку из его диапазона. Типа **worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2,C4:D5").Interior.Color=vbRed**.